# how to enable and disable input field in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am creating form from JSON using react hook form.I am using below library
https://www.react-hook-form.com/

ISSUE : In my JSON Each field have one property "disabled" . On the basis of property I want to disable or enable that field in **INITIAL render**  but after some time I need to enable field at some condition(example first name)

here is my JSON

```
const json = [
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "firstName",
    label: "First Name",
    disabled: true
  },
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "lastName",
    label: "Last Name",
    disabled: true
  }
];
```

Need to disable both field initially .But after 5 sec I need to enable first name field.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-form-context-forked-hlq9hm?file=/src/index.js

```
function App() {
  const methods = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      methods.setValue("firstName.disabled", false);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("000000");
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <FormBuilder
        jsonSchema={json}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onSubmitHandler={onSubmit}
        functionHandler={{
          onChange: onChange
        }}
      />
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

**JSON render form**

```
export default function FormBuilder({
  jsonSchema,
  functionHandler,
  onSubmitHandler
}) {
  const methods = useFormContext();
  const { register, handleSubmit, getValues, setValue } = methods;

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    onSubmitHandler(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {jsonSchema.map(({ type, name, label, disabled, ...rest }, index) => {
        if (type === "input") {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <label>{label}</label>
              <input
                {...register(name, { required: true })}
                disabled={getValues("disabled")}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        }

        // if (type === "select") {
        //   return (
        //     <React.Fragment key={index}>
        //       <label>{label}</label>
        //       <select
        //         {...register(name)}
        //         onChange={
        //           functionHandler[rest.changeHandler]
        //             ? functionHandler[rest.changeHandler]
        //             : null
        //         }
        //       >
        //         {rest.items.map((i, index) => (
        //           <option key={index} value={i.value}>
        //             {i.label}
        //           </option>
        //         ))}
        //       </select>
        //     </React.Fragment>
        //   );
        // }
      })}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

any suggestion  ? how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      methods.setValue("firstName.disabled", false);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);
```

Hi, instead of updating the disabled property using setValue you can update it using state

```
const [newJson , setNewJson] = useState(json)
useEffect(() => {


    setTimeout(() => {
         setNewJson(list => list.map((item, i) => // Array.protptype.map creates new 
 array
           i === 0
            ? {                               // new object reference for updated item
             ...item,                        // shallow copy previous item state
             disabled: false             // overwrite property being updated
          }
            : item
        ));
      }, 5000);
    }, []);
```

And then create new useEffect which depends on newJson value whenever its value get update the view will be re render

```
useEffect(() => {

}, [newJson])
```

After that pass newJson in props instead of json property like below

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
  <FormBuilder
    jsonSchema={newJson}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    onSubmitHandler={onSubmit}
    functionHandler={{
      onChange: onChange
    }}
  />
</FormProvider>
```

Then in formbuilder.js update the code. Instead of using getValue function we can directly access disabled property.

```
       <React.Fragment key={index}>
          <label>{label}</label>
          <input
            {...register(name, { required: true })}
            disabled={disabled}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
```

I hope this will help you. Please let me know if there is any doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update the json itself for a workaround. I tried in your codesandbox

Try the following code (I have removed unused code, you please add as your requirement) [Look at the useEffect part, updating the json itself]

1. index.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import FormBuilder from "./formbuilder";

import "./styles.css";

const defaultValue = { firstName: "", person: { sex: "" } };
const json = [
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "firstName",
    label: "First Name",
    disabled: true
  },
  {
    type: "input",
    name: "lastName",
    label: "Last Name",
    disabled: true
  }
];

function App() {
  const [jsonSchema, setJsonSchema] = useState(json);
  const methods = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setJsonSchema((prev) => {
        const cloned = [...prev];
        const firstNameIndex = cloned.findIndex((j) => j.name === "firstName");
        if (firstNameIndex > -1) {
          cloned[firstNameIndex].disabled = false;
        }
        return cloned;
      });
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  const onChange = () => {
    console.log("000000");
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <FormBuilder
        jsonSchema={jsonSchema}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onSubmitHandler={onSubmit}
        functionHandler={{
          onChange: onChange
        }}
      />
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

2. formbuilder.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
export default function FormBuilder({ jsonSchema, onSubmitHandler }) {
  const methods = useFormContext();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = methods;

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    onSubmitHandler(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {jsonSchema.map(({ type, name, label, disabled }, index) => {
        if (type === "input") {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <label>{label}</label>
              <input
                disabled={disabled}
                {...register(name, { required: true })}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        }
        return <></>;
      })}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```